# Mui Radio filled color

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am using Mui for styling a website I am working on. I was wondering if anyone had any insight on how to style a radio button so it is completely filled with one color while selected. This has to work with Mui Radio buttons.

Let me provide an example of how it should look.

[image: I want it to look like the first radio.]

I want it to look like the first radio button. It currently looks like the 4th in Mui.

I am also needing to do this with styled components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default icon by providing a different icon in the checkedIcon props (You can use Lens icon to achieve the first button). There are other icons as well at h[ere](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=circle&style=baseline). Pick the one you need

```
import Lens from "@material-ui/icons/Lens


return (
   <Radio
          value="example"
          label="example"
          checkedIcon={<Lens></Lens>}
        />
   )
```

Comment: Changing it to lens resolved what I needed. Thank you so much for your knowledge!

Comment: Hi, Does anyone know how to change the filled color of the radio button while it is not selected as well.?